# MVC mini profiler from Stack Overflow (installation)

Tags: c#, asp.net, profiling, asp.net-4.0, mvc-mini-profiler

I've downloaded the mini profiler:
http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

I'm using ASP.net 4.0 with webforms (VS 2010).  I'm really confused how to install this.  I've opened the various projects included in the download, most don't open without errors.

I was sort of expecting a DLL just to include, but this is obviously wrong!  I've searched for installation instructions but can't find any.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Well, the Getting started section in the documentation really explains it all. What are you struggling with?

Comment: @Alexn, the download doesn't seem to have that documentation! Can't see it on Github either (I'm new to Github) where is this documentation?

Comment: it's on the page you linked to.

Comment: @alexn that seems to show me how to use it just fine, but my question is about installing it.  I don't know how to add it to my current website so that I can use it as described in the getting started doc

Comment: So you want a binary? The easiest way is to download it using Nuget.

Comment: @alexn awesome thanks!  It works!  (Sorry if this was a noob question I'm still quite new to .net coming from classic ASP and it's new to me)

Comment: @alexn You should convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to download it is via [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/miniprofiler). Just right click on the project you want to add it to, click on `Manage Nuget Packages` and search for MiniProfiler, then just click install. Another option is to bring up the [Package Manager Console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console) and type:

```
Install-Package MiniProfiler
```